# Is this Raffle stacked against us? The organization holds 49 of the 200 tickets!

Tags: probability

This is a reverse raffle where the last ticket wins if they last 5 numbers choose not to contine (they would split the prize). Then the last 4 decide to split or continue, etc.

The organization has 49 unsold tickets and will still holf the raffle. How does this effect the purchasers assuming they each bought 1 ticket?

Comment: This is not clear.  "the last ticket wins if they last 5 numbers choose not to contine" does not make sense.

Comment: @lulu I believe that means: Entrants are eliminated as their number is drawn. When all except one entrant has been eliminated, that person wins the prize. Remaining entrants may split the pool at any time.

Comment: @DanielMathias  maybe...but it seems eccentric.  How does that differ from choosing $5$ "first round winners", giving them the option to share, and if they decline, selecting one ultimate winner from those five?

Comment: @lulu Choosing 5 'first round winners' may result in choosing 5 unsold tickets. The question specifically asks how the unsold tickets affect the reverse raffle in which drawn tickets are non-winners.

Comment: @DanielMathias  Well..whichever order you go in, if you include the unsold tickets in the draw, your process might select for them.  The OP should really weigh in here as to the rules and what sort of impact was of interest.  For instance, a large block of unsold tickets obviously lowers the payout and increases the probability of a win.  Is that what is being asked?  (assuming the proceeds from the sales are part of the prize, which of course might not be the case).

Comment: To clarify: A reverse raffle adds to the excitement as the last ticket is the winner. But to make it more interesting when down to 5 remaining tickets, the holders confer, they may split the prize money or if even one wants to continue another losing ticket is pulled. That process of decision making continues until they unanimously decide to split the prize or the last loser is drawn, the remaining ticket in would then get the whole prize

Comment: The prize amount is $3,000. It does not matter if all tickets are sold. That pize is either divided among the last 5 (or 4, or 3, or 2 tickets) or the last ticket- the only true winner is drawn.

Comment: This is an interesting question now you've clarified the process.. It would be great if you could put the explanation in the question—otherwise there's a risk of it being "closed as not clear what you're asking" even though you've made it clear in your comments.

Comment: What happens if some of the $49$ tickets are among the last $5$?  Or is that impossible?  If the $49$ tickets are not part of the drawing, the chances for each individual are $1/151$ instead of $1/200$

Answer (score 0):

The unsold tickets do not affect the outcome.

As each unsold ticket is drawn, no entrant is eliminated from the raffle. When there is only one entrant remaining, or when the last few entrants split the prize, the number of unsold tickets not drawn will not be irrelevant.